# How do you disable auto build in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4

The latest Xcode builds while coding... It gets stuff wrong and slows my Mac down. How do I disable this and have it build on demand?

Comment: Have you looked through the [Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html)?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> General and disable Live Issues in Editors and in Issue Navigator

*Update: It's called **Show Live Issues** in the latest Xcode versions*

Comment: This has become very laggy in xcode 7, (to the point where just scrolling through actual compile errors is a problem), fix still applies 4 years later!

Comment: Xcode still recompiles every project on every my action - switch file, insert char and so on. It's really annoying.

Comment: It is caused by the IB_DESIGNABLE definitions in the source header files.
You can stop by following steps:
1. Open Story Board
2. Editor -> Automatically refresh view ( Uncheck this)

Comment: Shiv Kumar, this is so absurd. IB_DESIGNABLE causes App services to rebuild while editing.

Comment: Or you can keep the wonderful functionality of IB_DESIGNABLE just by closing you storyboard if it is opened in a tab.

Answer (score 38):

If you have any `IB_DESIGNABLE` in source files, the system's live tracker will check for issues in StoryBoard too. It may leads to unnecessary building.

To disable it-

> Open Storyboard file. Editor -> Automatically Refresh Views (Uncheck)

If you needs to *Disable Live issue tracking*

> XCode -> Preferences -> General -> Issues -> Uncheck Live Issues