# Xcode Swift App - Automatic Compilation Messes Up Autocomplete

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, macos-sierra

Often, when working on a Swift app in Xcode 8.0/7.3.1, I find that the app automatically (without any input from me) starts compiling source files. It does this every minute or two.

This wouldn't normally be an issue - who doesn't like faster compilation times? But I find that it really messes up Swift Autocomplete. Now, a full 50% of the time, Swift Autocomplete doesn't work. I have to wait for the compilation to finish until autocomplete/syntax highlighting starts to work again. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I depend heavily (perhaps *too* heavily) on Xcode's Swift Autocomplete feature. It's not a problem with my machine either - this occurs on multiple computers, both with 32GB DDR4 RAM, state of the art components, so these are NOT slow machines, and they both have (independent) clean Sierra installs. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's compiling or is it indexing?

Comment: It's definitely compiling - it runs the shell scripts and everything. And it just keeps going. Over...and over....and over....

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434968/how-do-you-disable-auto-build-in-xcode