# Xcode randomly starts build on its own

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I have a weird problem with Xcode 11.5 where sometimes it would just randomly start a build on its own. The Stop button is greyed out so I can't stop the build any other way than quitting Xcode.

I've searched for answers, but they are all related to rebuilding project after modofying something in Interface Builder, which is not the case for me - I'm not doing anything with Interface Builder, or any class that has anything to do with a Storyboard or Xib file, a build will just randomly start withour the possibility to stop it.

I don't think it's related to "Live issue tracking" setting, because instead of just recompiling the file you're working on, in my case Xcode will trigger a clean build of an entire project, which cannot be stopped.

Is there a setting in Xcode that will trigger this automatic build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable auto build in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434968/how-do-you-disable-auto-build-in-xcode)

Comment: I don't think that's the cause. Live issue tracking will recompile the file you're working on, while my issue is that once in a while Xcode will trigger a clean build of an entire project.

Comment: What is shown in the Report Navigator for the build?